# Word frequency count in 2 files

Tags: java, count

I have wrote Java code to count sum of occurrences. It uses 2 `.txt` files as input and gives words and frequencies as output.

I would also like to print, which file how many times contains a given word. Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
public class JavaApplication2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {     
        Path filePath1 = Paths.get("test.txt");
        Path filePath2 = Paths.get("test2.txt");

        Scanner readerL = new Scanner(filePath1);
        Scanner readerR = new Scanner(filePath2);

        String line1 = readerL.nextLine();
        String line2 = readerR.nextLine();

        String text = new String();
        text=text.concat(line1).concat(line2);

        String[] keys = text.split("[!.?:;\\s]");
        String[] uniqueKeys;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(text);
        uniqueKeys = getUniqueKeys(keys);

        for(String key: uniqueKeys)
        {
            if(null == key)
            {
                break;
            }           
            for(String s : keys)
            {
                if(key.equals(s))
                {
                    count++;
                }               
            }
            System.out.println("["+key+"] frequency : "+count);
            count=0;
        }
    }

    private static String[] getUniqueKeys(String[] keys)
    {
        String[] uniqueKeys = new String[keys.length];

        uniqueKeys[0] = keys[0];
        int uniqueKeyIndex = 1;
        boolean keyAlreadyExists = false;

        for(int i=1; i<keys.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=uniqueKeyIndex; j++)
            {
                if(keys[i].equals(uniqueKeys[j]))
                {
                    keyAlreadyExists = true;
                }
            }           

            if(!keyAlreadyExists)
            {
                uniqueKeys[uniqueKeyIndex] = keys[i];
                uniqueKeyIndex++;               
            }
            keyAlreadyExists = false;
        }       
        return uniqueKeys;
    }
```

Comment: As a warning, your program as it stands does not read both files entirely, just the first line of each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, instead of using an array for unique keys, use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`. It's a lot more efficient.

Your best option is to run your processing over each line/file separately, and store these counts separately. Then merge the two counts to get the overall frequencies.

**More Detail:**

```
String[] keys = text.split("[!.?:;\\s]");
HashMap<String,Integer> uniqueKeys = new HashMap<>();

for(String key : keys){
    if(uniqueKeys.containsKey(key)){
        // if your keys is already in map, increment count of it
        uniqueKeys.put(key, uniqueKeys.get(map) + 1);
    }else{
        // if it isn't in it, add it
        uniqueKeys.put(key, 1);
    }
}

// You now have the count of all unique keys in a given text
// To print them to console

for(Entry<String, Integer> keyCount : uniqueKeys.getEntrySet()){
    System.out.println(keyCount.getKey() + ": " + keyCount.getValue());
}

// To merge, if you're using Java 8

for(Entry<String, Integer> keyEntry : uniqueKeys1.getEntrySet()){
    uniqueKeys2.merge(keyEntry.getKey(), keyEntry.getValue(), Integer::add);
}

// To merge, otherwise

for(Entry<String, Integer> keyEntry : uniqueKeys1.getEntrySet()){
    if(uniqueKeys2.containsKey()){
        uniqueKeys2.put(keyEntry.getKey(),
            uniqueKeys2.get(keyEntry.getKey()) + keyEntry.getValue());
    }else{
        uniqueKeys2.put(keyEntry.getKey(), keyEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use current construction and use separate keys lists for each file, how can I at the end "merge" them, sum values in them?

Comment: What's missing for it to answer your questions?

Comment: It is great, but I do not know, how can this implement counting and counting in both files(as an intersect).

Comment: So each of the sections of code are there for you to place where you want. You can write the top section twice, once for each file and then use one of the bottom sections to merge the results of them.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :** code for word(s) occurences (thanks @George)

This example is for a file, you can use it for multiple files :

```
public class MyTest {

    Map<String,Integer> mapTable;

    public MyTest(List<String> wordList){
        //initialize map
        makeMap(wordList);
    }

    public void makeMap(List<String> wordList){
        mapTable = new HashMap();

        for(int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++){
            //fill the map up
            mapTable.put(wordList.get(i), 0);
        }
    }

    //update occurences in a map
    public void updateMap(String [] _words){
        for(int i = 0; i < _words.length; i++){
            updateWordCount(_words[i]);
        }
    }

    public void updateWordCount(String _word){
        int value = 0;
        //check if a word present
        if(mapTable.containsKey(_word)){
            value = mapTable.get(_word);
            value++;
            mapTable.put(_word, value);
        }
    }

    public void DisplayCounts(){
        for( String key : mapTable.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Word : "+key+"\t Occurrence(s) :"+mapTable.get(key));
        }
    }

    public void getWordCount(){
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Jyo\\Desktop\\help.txt";
        String line = "";

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String _words[] = null;

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                _words = line.split(" ");

                updateMap(_words);
            }    

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        wordList.add("data");
        wordList.add("select");
        MyTest mt = new MyTest(wordList);
        mt.getWordCount();
        mt.DisplayCounts();


    }

}
```

Comment: This only counts the number of words, lines and characters. Not the number of occurrences of individual words.

Though the reading of multiple lines should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class file1{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
HashMap<String,Integer> words_fre = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
try{  

       File folder = new File("/home/jsrathore/Dropbox/Semester 6th/IR_Lab/lab_01/one");
       File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

       BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
       FileInputStream inputfilename=null;
       BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("outfilename.txt",false), "UTF-8"));

        for(File file : listOfFiles){           
           inputfilename= new FileInputStream(file); 
           /*System.out.println(file); */    
           bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputfilename, "UTF-8"));


             String s;
             while((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
               /*System.out.println(line);*/
                  s = s.replaceAll("\\<.*?>"," ");
                    if(s.contains("॥") || s.contains(":")|| s.contains("।")|| 
                     s.contains(",")|| s.contains("!")|| s.contains("?")){
                         s=s.replace("॥"," ");
                         s=s.replace(":"," ");
                         s=s.replace("।"," ");
                         s=s.replace(","," ");
                         s=s.replace("!"," ");
                         s=s.replace("?"," ");
                       }                                                   
                  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s," ");
                  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {         
                  /*out.write(st.nextToken()+"\n");*/
                  String str=(st.nextToken()).toString();
                  words.add(str);
                }
                for(String str : words){
                  if(words_fre.containsKey(str)){  
                           int a = words_fre.get(str);  
                           words_fre.put(str,a+1);             
                  }else{  
                      words_fre.put(str,1);/*uwords++;//unique words count */  
                  }                      
                }
                words.clear(); 

                  /*out.write("\n");
                  out.close();*/

             }             
             Object[] key =   words_fre.keySet().toArray();   
                  Arrays.sort(key);  
                  for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {  
                    //System.out.println(key[i]+"= "+words_fre.get(key[i]));
                 out.write(key[i]+" : "+words_fre.get(key[i]) +"\n");
               }


         }

            out.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

      }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
         System.out.println("Error in reading line");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            /*System.out.println("Error in reading line"+fileReader );*/
            ex.printStackTrace();
           }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, however below code will count word frequency efficiently if there are multiple files

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class WordCounter implements Runnable {
    private final Scanner scanner;
    private Map<String, AtomicLong> sharedCounter;

    public WordCounter(Scanner scanner, Map<String, AtomicLong> sharedCounter) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
        this.sharedCounter = sharedCounter;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (scanner == null) {
            return;
        }

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
            sharedCounter.putIfAbsent(word, new AtomicLong(0));
            sharedCounter.get(word).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Number of parallel thread to run
        int THREAD_COUNT = 10;

        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add path
        paths.add(Paths.get("test1.txt"));
        paths.add(Paths.get("test2.txt"));

        // Shared word counter
        Map<String, AtomicLong> sharedCounter = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);

        for (Path path : paths) {
            executor.execute(new WordCounter(new Scanner(path), sharedCounter));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println(sharedCounter);
    }
}
```